# Not easily debuggable crash on GDK at Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf()

Tags: c++, cairo, gdk, pixbuf

I have an multithreaded C++ application using GDK Cairo that inconsistently crashes on different lines but approximately all of the segmentation faults happen on the line `Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cr, image, 0, 0);` under a certain condition when I click my a 'save' button. (Using Glade as a UI framework).

```
std::string DefectWindowBase::save_image(Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>& image, std::string filename) {
    int width  = image->get_width();
    int height = image->get_height();

    Cairo::Format format = (image->get_has_alpha() ? Cairo::FORMAT_ARGB32 : Cairo::FORMAT_RGB24);
    auto surface         = Cairo::ImageSurface::create(format, width, height);
    auto cr              = Cairo::Context::create(surface);
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cr, image, 0, 0);
    cr->rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    cr->fill();

    sig_draw_rawoverlay.emit(cr, width, height, false);

    // Scale will not be drawn if it is not enabled
    sig_draw_scale.emit(cr, width, height);

    bool pathsHaveExternalFile = (mJobFilePaths.filePaths().size() >= 2);

    // Create a worker to save the local and remote images to file
    workers.push_back(std::make_shared<ImageWriteWorker>(surface, mJobFilePaths.getMainFilePath(),
                                                         pathsHaveExternalFile ? mJobFilePaths.filePaths().at(1) : "",
                                                         filename));

    // Connect the workers "completed" signal to a tidy up function to clean up the memory used after the images are saved
    workers.back()->sig_completed.connect(
        sigc::bind(sigc::mem_fun(this, &DefectWindowBase::tidy_worker), workers.back()));

    return filename;
}
```

Here is my IDE view with GDB pausing on the exception. `libgdk3.0.0` seems to be segfaulting but I do not have symbols. Any ideas why I might be segfault-ing here or any advice to debug further? I would ideally like to see exactly the root cause of the segfault.
[image: VSCode hooked to GDB showing the state of GDB in frame 2 with some variables values]

[image: Call stack]

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in the code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires showing a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: *I have an multithreaded C++ application using GDK Cairo* -- I don't want to be the bearer of bad news, but the person who can solve this is either yourself, or someone else who has your entire code and duplicates the error.  There is very little chance someone can debug  a multithreaded application with only a screenshot.

Comment: A "multithreaded C++ application [...] that inconsistently crashes" is often a sign that synchronization is missing somewhere.

Comment: If all else fails you can grab debug symbols for libgdk or build it yourself.

Comment: A `Glib::RefPtr` is a smart pointer, it seems very weird to be taking this by  reference instead of by copy, because your callback function now does not count as an extra reference to prevent the object from being deleted from under you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know I could have made it more reproduceable now so forgive me for that. Thanks @Botje for the helpful tip on passing by value instead of reference but that did not change anything. Going to build the lib from scratch.